# Firestore search for a specific document using whereequalto returns nothing

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement search feature inside firestore collection where it should fetch and display all document containing my entered string into my firestore recycler view but however my recycler view is always empty and is not returning any items.
Please take a look at my code:
//This method will load data into recycler view

```
private void initializeData()
    {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
      //Query query = null;
        Query  query;
        if (txt!=null){
             query = db.collection("Items").whereEqualTo(txt, true);

        }else{
              query = db.collection("Items");
        s="Items";
        }
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FriendsResponse> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendsResponse>()
                .setQuery(query, FriendsResponse.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FriendsResponse, FriendsHolder>(response) {
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(FriendsHolder holder, int position, FriendsResponse model) {
                String id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();
                holder.exname.setText(id);
                db.collection("Items").document(id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        String url= (String) document.getData().get("imageurl");
                        // Toast.makeText(getContext(),url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Glide.with(getContext()).load(url).into(holder.imgmenu);
                    }
                });  

            }

            @Override
            public FriendsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.menu_item, group, false);

                return new FriendsHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        };

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //int spaceInPixels = 200;
        DividerItemDecoration verticalDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
                DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL);
        Drawable verticalDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.divider_vertical);
        verticalDecoration.setDrawable(verticalDivider);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(verticalDecoration);

        DividerItemDecoration horizontalDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        Drawable horizontalDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.divider_horizontal);
        horizontalDecoration.setDrawable(horizontalDivider);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(horizontalDecoration);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is the code for my search bar:

```
public void search(){
        //setContentView(R.layout.view_feed_toolbar);
        searchBar = (MaterialSearchBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
        searchBar.setSpeechMode(false);
        searchBar.enableSearch();
        searchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
                String s = enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled";
                Toasty.info(getContext(), "Search " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();
                if (s.equals("disabled")){
                    searchBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    txt=null;
                    initializeData();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
            txt=text.toString();
            initializeData();
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific as to what part of the code is giving you trouble?

Comment: I'm facing problems with initializedata() method which is basically not fetching documents as per the query.

Comment: ok, yes, but what part? that 's a pretty big method for someone who is not familiar with your design/requirements. have you debugged your code? is it not getting values? is it getting values but not showing them? .... ? does all the code you assume is running actually runs?

Comment: either way, you should strive not to overcomplicate your code. for example: in your search method, why do you create that s variable to check in your condition, if you already base it on a boolean? just check the boolean value in the if statement.

Comment: `query = db.collection("Items").whereEqualTo(txt, true);` This query will look for documents which contain key `txt` and value as `true`, probably not what you want.

Comment: I clearly said i'm facing problems with query which need to search for specific document and display them. it's this part
  Query  query;
        if (txt!=null){
             query = db.collection("Items").whereEqualTo(txt, true);

        }else{
              query = db.collection("Items");
        s="Items";
        }

Comment: @Ranjan i didn't got you can you please help me understand

Comment: Explain in the question, how you want to filter your documents? What're your criteria for filtering out documents? It will be helpful if you can share the structure of your document.

Comment: @Ranjan i want to fetch all documents containing my search string which is txt

Comment: Read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries. They are searching for `capital` in documents since documents have `capital` key in them. Do your documents have key with your search strings?

Comment: @Ranjan still not working i tried searching for exact name but it doesn't fetch anything

Comment: It's not possible to help you further without knowing the structure and keys of your documents.